# Get Element ID - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know the `data-id` from the `li` element, but now i want the `id` value of the `li` element. How can I get this? Tried:

```
 var id = $('li[data-id="KnSubject[StId]"]').id;
 console.log(id); // UNDEFINED
```

Html Code:

```
<li role="treeitem" data-jstree="{&quot;icon&quot; : &quot;glyphicon glyphicon-pencil&quot;}" data-id="KnSubject[StId]" data-values="null" aria-selected="true" aria-level="3" aria-labelledby="j1_4_anchor" id="j1_4" class="jstree-node  jstree-leaf"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl" role="presentation"></i><a class="jstree-anchor jstree-clicked" href="#" tabindex="-1" id="j1_4_anchor"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon glyphicon glyphicon-pencil jstree-themeicon-custom" role="presentation"></i>Type dossieritem (StId)</a></li>
```

Comment: $('li[data-id="KnSubject[StId]"]').data('id'); try this line

Comment: jquery objects do not have an id property

Comment: `.id` is not a method of jQuery :)
Use `$('element').attr('id');`

Answer (score 4):

```
var id = $('li[data-id="KnSubject[StId]"]').attr('id');
console.log(id);
```

Comment: @Anna Jeanine If this answer helped you please mark it correct and upvote it... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use `attr` function.

```js
var elem = $('li[data-id="KnSubject[StId]"]');
console.log(elem.attr('id'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li role="treeitem" data-jstree="{&quot;icon&quot; : &quot;glyphicon glyphicon-pencil&quot;}" data-id="KnSubject[StId]" data-values="null" aria-selected="true" aria-level="3" aria-labelledby="j1_4_anchor" id="j1_4" class="jstree-node  jstree-leaf"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl" role="presentation"></i><a class="jstree-anchor jstree-clicked" href="#" tabindex="-1" id="j1_4_anchor"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon glyphicon glyphicon-pencil jstree-themeicon-custom" role="presentation"></i>Type dossieritem (StId)</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness reasons:

```
$('li[data-id="KnSubject[StId]"]').get(0).id
```

.get(0) retrieves the raw JS DOM Element.